Does running an NLP model generate 300 tonnes of CO₂?
The AI critic Kate Crawford writes in her book The Atlas of AI:

With a focus on trying to understand the carbon footprint of natural language processing (NLP) models, they began to sketch out potential estimates by running AI models over hundreds of thousands of computational hours. The initial numbers were striking. Strubell’s team found that running only a single NLP model produced more than 660,000 pounds of carbon dioxide emissions, the equivalent of five gas-powered cars over their total lifetime (including their manufacturing) or 125 round-trip flights from New York to Beijing.

Does running an Natural Language Processing (NLP) model (like one of the GPTs) produce over 660,000 pounds (300 tonnes) of CO₂?
Related question: Does AI use lots of water?

Who is "they" and what references does Crawford supply to support the claim?

To answer my own question: Crawford gives context in the text just before the quote (page 42) "AI researcher Emma Strubell and her team at the University of Massachusetts Amherst in 2019" and in the endnotes gives a reference to this paper.

So per the paper, they are estimating the energy needed to train a model. It's also likely that algorithms and hardware, and their energy efficiency, have changed a lot since 2019.

The book was published in 2021, though, so I suppose the 2019 study was more reasonably current at the time.

Just "running an AI model" and especially "running only a single NLP model" is ill-defined. A model isn’t a thing you can run. The closest may be training the model, running an instance of it on a specific input or running a service to handle input for a specific time. Does the text provide any more context on what is meant in this section?

How much CO2 is produced depends on how the power is generated. The number will be very different for coal power vs solar. The real statistic is the power needed.

@Schwern Perhaps assume an energy mix that is common in the USA. Btw, nearly 80% of my post have been removed, even the title was renamed (originally it was: “Extreme claims about generative AI's energy use”). It also included a claim about AI datacenter power use. It seems that on this site, questions have to be broken down to one single, precise claim. Which is very sad, since most peddlers of misinformation don't give us the courtesy to be precise.

@MisterMiyagi no, “running” is not clearly defined anywhere. Maybe it's supposed to mean: run for those “hundreds of thousands of computational hours”?

@viuser: Yes, unfortunately claims need to be specific and clear enough to be actually answerable. This one isn't. "Running" seems to refer to power consumption where as 300 tons of CO2 is an energy equivalent. In other words:  you need to state for "HOW LONG" you are running. Are we talking about running it for a single transaction, for a day, for a year or for it's entire lifetime. 300 tons CO2 isn't all that much. It's about 12 Tera Joules or the equivalent of 40 average households per year. Amazons Alexa has been trained over many years so that certainly took more energy than 40 houses.

@Hilmar well, even if I state it, I have to provide a source for it.  So yeah, it's sad - I guess the rules will have to become a bit more flexible, though. The good old, upstanding misinformation-peddler formulated their claims clearly and in a specific manner. But nowadays, they leave something out and manipulate us into inserting the missing bits. I read it as “Power consumption for a single user input” (and IMHO she wants us to read it that way). Btw, the IMHO more specific claim was removed from this post, which was that AI datacenters use as much power as the whole nation of Japan.

@viuser “Power consumption for a single user input”: that' would definitely be false. First: a single user output would be measured in energy and not in power. Second:  A major NLP such as Alexa or Siri process close to a billion inputs per day. 300 tons of CO2 per input would exceed the total emission of the planet in less than 3 hours. Can't be true.

Besides the ambiguity in what "running" is (Training the model once? Running inference once?), there is also ambiguity in what "NLP model" means. If the study is from a few years back, it would more likely be something based on BERT—but it could refer to a very wide range of things (latent Dirichlet allocation is a possible NLP model, say).
